# Sonatype Nexus OSS 3 content selector to query specific repositories

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I would like to know if Sonatype Nexus Repository OSS 3 supports querying on specific repositories, i.e, I need to filter the results from the `docker_hosted_repo`, but on the other hand, everything in `docker_group_repo` should be returned. According to the [official documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/access-control/content-selectors#ContentSelectors-ContentSelectorReference), the only available attributes are `format` and `path`.

Something like (pseudo expression):

```
format == "docker" and (path =~ "^my_compay/.*" and repo == "docker_hosted_repo") or (path =~ ".*" and repo == "docker_group_repo")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct format and path are the only expressions supported right now.

However, I suspect you can do what you stated without need.  When you create the content selector privilege it specifically asks you what repository.  You can make that more broad or narrow as suits your needs.  If you need multiple individual repositories you can create multiple privileges.

[image: Shown here]

After creating this privilege you can then assign it to the users you want.

The only confusion I can see with this method is if your example "docker_group_repo" contains "docker_hosted_repo".  Then I suspect you cannot be both permissive and restrictive at the same time.  It'd be like saying you can go into the bank to see your money but you can't see your money.